# Forex_python in custom function for Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, currency, forex

I am trying to build a custom function which can be applied to a pandas dataframe and convert an amount of some currency into the amount in my local currency (`DKK`) according to the exchange rate of the last day of the previous month (With base in the `Pstng Date`). 
So for instance, if the posting date is 2016-03-12, I want to convert the amount according to the exchange rate of 2016-02-28.

I am using the [forex-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/forex-python) library with the convert function - Here's my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Crcy': ['DKK','CAD','GBP','USD'],
    'Pstng Date': ['2017-01-12','2015-12-15','2016-06-06','2017-08-12'],
    'Amount': [100,5000,40,50]
})
```

And here is my function:

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
c = CurrencyRates()

def convert_rates2(amount,currency,PstngDate):
    if currency != 'DKK':
        return c.convert(base_cur=currency,dest_cur='DKK',amount=amount \
                         ,date_obj=PstngDate - datetime.timedelta(PstngDate.strftime('%d')))
    else:
        return amount
```

The way I am trying to apply it to the df:

```
df['Amount, DKK'] = np.vectorize(convert_rates2)(
    amount=df['Amount'],
    currency=df['Crcy'],
    PstngDate=df['Pstng Date']
)
```

However, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Does anyone have an idea of how to approach this? Different approaches are very welcome as well.

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def convert_rates2(amount,currency,PstngDate):
    PstngDate = datetime.strptime(PstngDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    if currency != 'DKK':
        return c.convert(base_cur=currency,dest_cur='DKK',amount=amount \
                     ,date_obj=PstngDate - timedelta(PstngDate.day))
    else:
        return amount
```

This would give this result:

```
df['Amount, DKK'] = np.vectorize(convert_rates2)(
    amount=df['Amount'],
    currency=df['Crcy'],
    PstngDate=df['Pstng Date']
)


df
Out[56]: 
   Amount Crcy  Pstng Date  Amount, DKK
0     100  DKK  2017-01-12          100
1    5000  CAD  2015-12-15        26375
2      40  GBP  2016-06-06          390
3      50  USD  2017-08-12          317
```

Comment: Thanks very much - Works like a charm. Would you happen to know what the wrong thing about my approach is?

Comment: `PstngDate` is a string, so you cannot take parts of it like the month, day etc. In the second line in the function, I make it a datetime object, from there, you can substract the date extracting it `timedelta(PstngDate.day)`